# How do I display this simple C# app to the console?

Tags: c#, format, console-application

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("input.txt");
        int lineCount = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

        List<string> materials = new List<string>();
        List<string> premiumMaterials = new List<string>();

        PremiumChocolateFactory premiumChocolate;
        ChocolateFactory chocolate;

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] line = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');

            for (int i = 2; i < line.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (line[line.Length - 1] == "premium")
                {
                    premiumMaterials.Add(line[i]);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 2; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!line.Contains("premium"))
                {
                    materials.Add(line[i]);
                }
            }

            premiumChocolate = new PremiumChocolateFactory(line[0], int.Parse(line[1]), premiumMaterials);
            chocolate = new ChocolateFactory(line[0], int.Parse(line[1]), materials);
            Console.WriteLine(premiumChocolate);
            Console.WriteLine(chocolate);
        }
    }
}
```

3

```
dark chocolate;81;cocoa;sugar;cocoa butter;premium  
milk chocolate;70;cocoa powder;cocoa butter;milk  
white chocolate;0;sugar;cocoa butter;milk
```

The "input.txt" file contains the above information. The first line is the number of different chocolates, and the rest is like this:
chocolate type;amount of cocoa;materials(3 of them);and whether the chocolate is premium.

If it is premium, you have to create a PremiumChocolateFactory object, if not, just a regular ChocolateFactory one. My premium chocolate object displays on the console just fine, but the regular chocolates gets all jumbled up. The PremiumChocolateFactory is inherited from ChocolateFactory. I have overridden the ToString method in my ChocolateFactory class.

```
return $"Chocolate type: {chocolateType} | Materials: {string.Join(", ", material)} | Cocoa amount: {cocoaAmount}%";
```

I know that the Console.WriteLines shouldn't be inside the while loop but I get an error if they are outside lol.

[image]

Comment: What's your expect result or what is the question?

Comment: @Steve I did a bunch of times but it led me nowhere. I first thought that the list wasn't receiving the assigned values but I figured out from the debugger that it did, just the displaying is wrong.

Comment: @D-Shih Well, correctly displaying the information to the console obviously. As you can see, that's not currently the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would change some thing in your code to have a cleaner interface against your two classes. First of all the two classes should be something like these

```
public class ChocolateFactory
{

    public string ChocolateType { get; set; }
    public int CocoaAmount { get; set; }
    public List<string> Materials {get;set;} = new List<string>();
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Chocolate type: {ChocolateType} | Materials: {string.Join(", ", Materials)} | Cocoa amount: {CocoaAmount}%, IsPremium=No";

    }
}
public class PremiumChocolateFactory : ChocolateFactory
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Chocolate type: {ChocolateType} | Materials: {string.Join(", ", Materials)} | Cocoa amount: {CocoaAmount}%, IsPremium=Yes";

    }
}
```

So, now those classes have a public `List<string>` for the Materials and thus there is no need to have your own lists in the code

```
List<ChocolateFactory> myChocos = new List<ChocolateFactory>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"e:\temp\input.txt"))
{
    int lineCount = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string[] line = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
        bool isPremium = line[line.Length - 1] == "premium";
        int length = isPremium ? line.Length - 1 : line.Length;

        var t = isPremium ? new PremiumChocolateFactory() 
                          : new ChocolateFactory();

        t.ChocolateType = line[0];
        t.CocoaAmount = Int32.Parse(line[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < length; i++)
            t.Materials.Add(line[i]);
        myChocos.Add(t);
    }
}

....
foreach(var x in myChocos)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```